# Lambda Does Not Work In Websocket Session

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

I just encountered a peculiar little problem:

```
javax.websocket.Session session = //...
// this works
newSession.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        MyWebSocket.this.onMessage(message);
    }
});
// these don't work
newSession.addMessageHandler((MessageHandler.Whole<String>) MyWebSocket.this::onMessage);
newSession.addMessageHandler((MessageHandler.Whole<String>) message -> MyWebSocket.this.onMessage(message));


void onMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Does anybody know why lambda expressions won't work in this instance? There is no compile error, no exception, no nothing. The method ''onMessage'' is just not called.

I use Java 1.8.0_65 and the Tyrus reference implementation 1.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please see https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/websocket_api_1_1_released

tldr; you have to use [`Session#addMessageHandler(Class<T> clazz, MessageHandler.Whole<T> handler)`](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs-javax.websocket/1.1/javax/websocket/Session.html#addMessageHandler(java.lang.Class,%20javax.websocket.MessageHandler.Whole))

```
/**
* Register to handle to incoming messages in this conversation. A maximum of one message handler per
* native websocket message type (text, binary, pong) may be added to each Session. I.e. a maximum
* of one message handler to handle incoming text messages a maximum of one message handler for
* handling incoming binary messages, and a maximum of one for handling incoming pong
* messages. For further details of which message handlers handle which of the native websocket
* message types please see {@link MessageHandler.Whole} and {@link MessageHandler.Partial}.
* Adding more than one of any one type will result in a runtime exception.
*
* @param clazz   type of the message processed by message handler to be registered.
* @param handler whole message handler to be added.
* @throws IllegalStateException if there is already a MessageHandler registered for the same native
*                               websocket message type as this handler.
*/
public void addMessageHandler(Class<T> clazz, MessageHandler.Whole<T> handler);
```

in order to use lambdas as message handers.

Answer (score -2):

From my understanding `MessageHandler` would need to be a `@FunctionalInterface` to allow lambda expressions here, which isn't the case.

Comment: ["However, the compiler will treat any interface meeting the definition of a functional interface as a functional interface regardless of whether or not a FunctionalInterface annotation is present on the interface declaration."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)
You don't need the Annotation to use it as lambda

Comment: Also there would be a compile error if that was the case.